# Open Xcode 4 using Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

i have install Xcode 5 final version on my mac using Mac App Store, but i need to open m'y projects using Xcode4, how can i do that ?

```
<terminal> open xcode4
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do u have both xcode now in your mac?

Comment: I had Xcode 4 and update to Xcode 5

Comment: xcode 5 from app store replaces xcode 4. Go to developer portal downloads and dl xcode 4.6 from there. https://developer.apple.com/downloads/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question it sounds like you want to do this from the command line, so just use `open -a` to specify which version of Xcode to use, e.g.:

```
$ open -a "/Applications/Xcode 4"
```

or:

```
$ open -a "/Applications/Xcode 4" /path/to/myproject
```